# WHERE AND SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to have 2 where clause. The SQL statement works before I put

```
AND fborders.date="+todayDate);
```

So is there a error at my sql statement because it does not work?

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date date = new Date();
String todayDate = dateFormat.format(date);


("
SELECT Id,Name,quantity,date,time,
FROM orders
WHERE status='pending'
  AND date="+todayDate
);
```

Comment: You need to quote the date

Comment: Or else use prepared statements and pass the date as a parameter. Then you don't have to quote it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed single quote sign. `Date` needs quotes around that.

Here you go:

```
AND fborders.date='" + todayDate + "'"
```

Answer (score 3):

The date needs to be in quotes too. Change it to this:

```
AND date='" + todayDate + "'"
```

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking you don't have to pass todays date as a parameter at all.

Assuming that your `DATE` column is a `DATE` type, you could just use:

```
SELECT Id,Name,quantity,date,time
  FROM orders
 WHERE status='pending'
   AND date=current_date()
```

or is `DATE` is a `VARCHAR` column:

```
SELECT Id,Name,quantity,date,time
  FROM orders
 WHERE status='pending'
   AND date=date_format(current_date(), '%d/%m/%Y')
```